# Lab environment for Active Directory learning without a real DNS

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I am trying to setup a lab type of environment for learning Active directory environment using Virtual machines on HyperV. I am planning to create a VM using Windows 2008 R2 Standard. When I google around on step of setting up Active Directory and Domain controller, one of the requirement is to configure TCP/IP and DNS network configuration. What I am confused about if I don’t have any static IP address or registered domain name  (like www.mydomain.com etc), can I still setup DNS and proceed with setting up my lab for AD setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, DNS is used to resolve hostnames and allow any machines connected to the domain to contact the Domain Controller. Just setup your domain as [Your Domain Name here].local to avoid any conflicts with external domains and you're all set.